# Can nginx cache proxied pages to be later used as stale content when backend is down

Tags: caching, nginx, proxy

We have a use case wherein we are using nginx as a proxy, but if the backend is down, nginx should be able to serve content out of the cache (only if the backend is down).

As far as I know, nginx would not cache pages that are marked as proxy.

One way to achieve this would be to set those page caches to the smallest time possible in nginx which is 1 second I think, so that nginx caches it and then if subsequent requests fail, nginx can pick up this stale data.

```
    proxy_cache_key "$scheme$host$uri$is_args$args";

    proxy_cache_valid 200 302 1s;
    proxy_cache_valid 404     1s;

    proxy_cache_use_stale   error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 http_404;
```

The problem with this approach is that it should still be caching it for 1 second, which I don't want.

And If I change it to 0 seconds, it doesnt cache at all, so there is nothing in the cache to fallback to incase backend servers go down.

Let me know if anybody has dealt with a similar use case and/or have ideas around this.

Thanks